# android: jetpack compose lazycolumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can i show the lazycolumn from below?
by default it shows me the list from above

```
   LazyColumn(){
        itemsIndexed(items = chat){ index, chat ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 1.dp, start = 6.dp, bottom = 1.dp, end = 6.dp)) 
             {
                if(chat.sender.equals(MyId)){
                    ItemRigth(chat)
                }
                else{
                    ItemLeft(chat)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you set the `reverseLayout` param to true, the items will appear from the bottom.

```
LazyColumn(
    reverseLayout= true, // << here
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) { .. }
```

Comment: _or_ aleternatively kotlin's `List` provides a pretty nice `List<T>.reversed()` method which can be used in the ViewModel. (Just trying to complement your answer.) +1

Comment: with this approach, the List object sort order is reversed. The question is regarding order of the list items are drawn on the screen...

Comment: the property reverseLayout shows me error

Comment: Which error? Which jetpack compose version are you using?
It's working for me on beta-02.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn

Set the reverseLayout parameter to true.